# Probability of parking next to specific person

Tags: probability

Given that there are 10 parking spots available all in a row and 10 employees come to work everyday (including myself), what is the probability that I park next to Dave, who is also an employee?

EDIT: My thinking is that it would be (2*9!)/10! which is 1/5.

Comment: answered before I saw your edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

number of possible ways for 10 people to park: $10!$

Number of possible ways for 8 people to park, and you and dave to park together,  $9!$

Number or arrangements of you and dave: $2!$

So $\cfrac{9! \cdot 2!}{10!}$

Edit: Just to add a different way to do it. There are 2 spots where 1 person can park next to you (the end spots) and then 1/9th of the time dave can fill one of those sports. So $\frac{2}{10}\cdot \frac{1}{9}$

Then the other 8 spots, the chances dave parks next to you is 1 minus the chance that he doesnt. So $\frac{8}{10}\cdot (1 - \frac{8}{9}\frac{7}{8})$. If you add all that together, you also get a probability of $\frac{1}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

We can ignore everyone but you and Dave.

**Method 1:**  For each of the ten ways you could park, Dave can park in nine ways.  As for the favorable cases, there are nine pairs of adjacent parking spots and two ways you and Dave could park in each such pair.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{9 \cdot 2}{10 \cdot 9} = \frac{1}{5}$$

**Method 2:**  There are $\binom{10}{2}$ pairs of parking spaces that you and Dave could occupy.  Of these, nine are adjacent.  Hence, the desired probability is 
$$\frac{9}{\dbinom{10}{2}} = \frac{9}{45} = \frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method 3** : $Pr = \dfrac29\cdot\dfrac9{10}$

$\frac29$ *Pr* that you are next to Dave in circular seating,
and $\frac9{10}$ *Pr* that the circle is not *"straightened"* by cutting between you two.